# Ksql: applying a filter on a KTable produce records with null value

Tags: ksqldb

I am wondering if the behavior I am experiencing with ksql is to be expected.

I create a table out of a topic, after what I create a table that select some field of that table with a condition on one of the column I.e. using the where clause.

That second table is a persistent query. Hence I inspect the output topic and all the record are in there either with null value or with value for the record that met the condition on the column.

However when I query that ktable with a select * I do not see those records with null value. In other words,querying the Ktable from the persistent query give me the result that I expect. It is the output topic that looks strange. Why giving me the records that I don’t need with a null value, and the one I need at the same time in the same topics ? Why the out topic of the persistent query which basically only apply a where clause, does not only contain the record that meet the where clause condition ?

If that is to be expected is there a way around that ?